# JavaScript RegEx (0-100) but not leading 0

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a RegEx working for 0-100% including 0, but not as a leading number.
EXAMPLE valid inputs would be 0, 10, 34, 100 and invalid would be 00, 01, 045, 000, or any number larger than 100.

I'm finding a lot of examples with 1-100 on here but not single 0, and my lack of understanding RegEx isn't helping me make the proper adjustments. Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us an example of your efforts.

Comment: Uh, `str.indexOf("0") === 0 && str.length > 1`

Comment: @adeneo That would return true on a bunch of invalid input, along with that OP is asking for a regex for this.

Comment: Fyi, there are numerous regex numb range generators available. Some are online, some are included with [software](http://www.regexformat.com/version6_files/Rx5_ScrnSht0.jpg).

Comment: Thanks sln, I didn't know. I'll look into that too. The solution below helped me in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:\d|[1-9]\d|100)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4EO01c/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capturing group

  - `\d`: match numbers from `0` to `9`
  - `|`: OR
  - `[1-9]\d`: match numbers from `10` to `99`
  - `|`: OR
  - `100`: match `100`
- `)`: End non-capturing group
- `$`: End

Comment: Why do you have a it as non-capturing group? Doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: One should avoid unnecessary capturing groups in regex to save memory and get the numbering right when using in a regex with capturing groups.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - A group is necessary so that the anchors will apply to each alternation.

Comment: Thank you. This worked, and I appreciate the explanation, that was very helpful to help me understand more. I'm working on another range based RegEx, let's see if I learned something ;)